# left / right angle accent

Tags: math-mode, accents

Is there a LaTeX math package that provides "angle" accents?

For example, a "right angle accent" applied to "a" would look like this:

[image]

I produced this image using the `COMBINING LEFT ANGLE ABOVE` Unicode character, which however does not seem to work in XeLaTeX, and there isn't a `COMBINING RIGHT ANGLE ABOVE` character anyway.

If not, is there another recommendation to denote a lower / upper bound? I've seen the convention to use a "L"or "U" as sub- or superscripts, but don't like that.

Comment: Would it be in math mode?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
$\accentset{\lnot}{a}$ or $\accentset{\lnot}{\text{a}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In math mode, you probably want `\mathrm{a}` instead of `\text{a}`. With `\text`, the formatting of the surrounding text (such as italics or bold) bleeds through.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks! Yes, that's true. However, we do not know yet what the OP want's in the end. Maybe they want `\textbf{$\accentset{\lnot}{\text{a}}$wesome}`. Another concern is that `\accentset` does not seem to cooperate with `hyperref` in sections and the like.

Answer (score 3):

The right angle accent ◌̚ (U+031A) is `\droang` in `unicode-math`.  The fonts XITS Math and STIX Two Math both have it, but its positioning with STIX Two is off.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\( \droang{a} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: XITS Math font sample]

You can combine the accent from XITS Math with any math font:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=\droang]{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
\( \droang{a} \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample]

Answer (score 2):

You can use, [as suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539583/4427), `accents`. In case you also need the reverse shape, there are two ways: one is more efficient, using `wasysym`, but it has the defect that the symbol may not blend with `\lnot` (if the math font is not Computer Modern). The second solution uses the same symbol, but horizontally reflected, so it automatically blends.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,accents}

\usepackage{wasysym} % for \invneg
\usepackage{graphicx} % for the homemade reflected symbol

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\blnot}{{\mathpalette\b@lnot\relax}}
\newcommand{\b@lnot}[2]{\reflectbox{$\m@th#1\lnot$}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\accentset{\lnot}{a}+\accentset{\invneg}{a}
\]
\[
\accentset{\lnot}{a}+\accentset{\blnot}{a}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]